# Combine string where part of the header is identical

Tags: r

I have a file like this:

```
>mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121 Mus musculus let-7g-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU
>mmu-let-7g-3p MIMAT0004519 Mus musculus let-7g-3p
ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
>mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122 Mus musculus let-7i-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU
>mmu-let-7i-3p MIMAT0004520 Mus musculus let-7i-3p
CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
....
....
```

I would like to combine the Strings that have identical header based on this part of the header `mmu-let-7g, mmu-let-7i, etc`

Output:

```
>mmu-let-7g
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
>mmu-let-7i
UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file using `readLines`, remove the suffix part of the "lines" starting with "-" ('lines1').  This will only remove the suffix of the header lines.  Create an index ('indx') of TRUE/FALSE.  Separate the header lines from the bases, use the aggregating functions (`tapply`) grouped by "headers" and `paste` the base lines together.  You can get the expected result from rearranging the "v1" to get "v2"

```
lines <- readLines('file.txt')
lines1 <- sub('-.. .*', '', lines)
indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
v1 <- unname(tapply(lines1[!indx], lines1[indx],
                           FUN=paste, collapse=' '))

v2 <-  c(rbind(unique(lines1[indx]), v1))
v2 
# [1] ">mmu-let-7g"                                  
# [2] "UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC"
# [3] ">mmu-let-7i"                                  
# [4] "UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU"
```

#### Update

Suppose the strings within in a header span multiple lines.  (In this case, it will be the same result.)  Here, you can split the lines ("lines1") to a "list" based on creating a grouping variable (`cumsum(grepl(...)`) from locations of header lines.  Then, `paste` the multi-lines together and `unlist`.  Aggregate using `tapply` as above.

```
lines2 <-  unlist(lapply(split(lines1, cumsum(grepl('>', lines1))),
         function(x) c(x[1],paste(x[-1], collapse=''))), 
                          use.names=FALSE)
v1 <- tapply(lines2[!indx], lines2[indx], FUN=paste, collapse=' ')
v2 <- c(rbind(names(v1), unname(v1)))
v2
#[1] ">mmu-let-7g"                                  
#[2] "UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC"
#[3] ">mmu-let-7i"                                  
#[4] "UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step will be reading the multi-line format. The `scan` function allows this if youalso supply a list as the what argument (and you cna use a named list. This is suitable for conversion to a dataframe:

```
> dat <- as.data.frame( scan(what =list( V1="", V2="", V3="", V4="", V5="", V6=""), multi.line=TRUE)  )
1: >mmu-let-7g-5p MIMAT0000121 Mus musculus let-7g-5p
1: UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU
2: >mmu-let-7g-3p MIMAT0004519 Mus musculus let-7g-3p
2: ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC
3: >mmu-let-7i-5p MIMAT0000122 Mus musculus let-7i-5p
3: UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU
4: >mmu-let-7i-3p MIMAT0004520 Mus musculus let-7i-3p
4: CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU
5: 
Read 4 records
```

You then want to paste items based on a substring of the first or 5th argument. The exact rules will depend on your larger knowledge of the naming conventions for these nucleotide sequences, microRNAs perhaps? The tapply function does operations within categories defined by its second argument. Here I have simply trimmed off the dash (-) and last 2 characters of the fifth item but if you wanted the species designator you could work on the first column:

```
> tapply(dat$V6, sub("-..$","", dat$V5), paste, collapse=" ")
                                         let-7g 
"UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC" 
                                         let-7i 
"UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU"
```